# Post-build Actions for Jenkins multi-configuration job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to perform some post build actions in a multi-configuration job, for example, check the status of configuration after all the configs are finished, and execute some scripts if any of them completed with result FAILURE.

However if I set a Post Build Task, it will be performed after the build process of each configuration, not after the parent job.

Other post build action like trigger builds on other projects can only be performed after parent job, and Editable email notification can trigger email for matrix projects or parent job only. So I think there might be a way that I can run script only after parent job.

Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Multijob](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) plugin which allows you to place jobs in phases

For example, matrix job in phase 1.

After that you can add additional phases of other jobs or just add build/postbuild steps as you can in a freestyle

Incidentally, you do not need to trigger additional jobs with this plugin, just add them in as additional phases. Jobs within phases run in parallel and phases run sequentially

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having your configuration results determine your parent jobs status. Based on that status you could then have it trigger a separate job that runs your "post build" scripts.